# List in list view with onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am working on an application with Jsoup and aSyncTask. I am trying to get a html table in a list view, but I am having trouble with getting the data in the list view. I know I should use the onPostExecute method. The error is that the method is not called so you should use @Override so method will be called, but then I am having problem with calling the list view and setting the list in the list view.

If someone has an alternative solution that will also be appreciated.

This my code:

```
public class Cluka2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    Document document = null;
    public List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView listView = null;
    Context context = null;


    public Cluka2(ArrayList<String> list,Context mContext) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context= mContext;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://tennisnaarden.planmysport.com/portal/page/pmsportal30/TVNaarden/Toernooien/Clubtoernooi").get();

            Elements elements = document.select("#pcnt1383_8158836_1383_4326089_4326089 td:first-child");

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

                list.add(elements.get(i).text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        Toernooien.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

}
```

This code has no errors when the application is running, but it is not displaying a list with data.

This is my activity class:

```
public class ClubkampioenschappenSingleenDubbel extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    Document doc = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clubkampioenschappen_singleen_dubbel);
        this.setTitle("Clubkampioenschappen Single en Dubbel");

        new Cluka2(list, context).execute();

        ListView Toernooien = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Toernooien);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_clubkampioenschappen_singleen_dubbel, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `context` is null. where is it initialized?

Comment: Context context = null;  I tried this for onPostExecute method for displaying the list in list view. You need the context.

Comment: You need to context. You can get that in in your application components like activity (ActivityName.this). Or in fragment `getActivtiy()`.

Comment: also change 'AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>'  to 'AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>'  and 'return list.toString();' to 'return list';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already setting up your list in your `doInBackground()` So, you can just passing result string as "Success" or "Failure". and based on that you can do relevant code in your `onPostExecute()`

According to your structure of AsynsTask your `onPostExecute()` method should be look like below :

```
@override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            Onderdelen.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
```

In Addition to that, you will have to initiate your context as well in constructor.

```
public Cluka2(ArrayList<String> list,Context mContext) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context=mContext;
    }
```

Also you will need to intiate your `Listview` on `onCreate()` of your activity. So, remove this line from `onPostExecute()` and place it in `onCreate()`.

```
 ListView Onderdelen = (ListView) listView.findViewById(R.id.Toernooien);
```

**Edit :**

inside your activity's onCreate() :

Change

```
 new Cluka2(list, context).execute();

        ListView Toernooien = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Toernooien);
```

To

```
 ListView Toernooien = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Toernooien);
 new Cluka2(list, ClubkampioenschappenSingleenDubbel.this).execute();
```

Comment: I thought this would work but this is the error I got: java.lang.NullPointerException
            com.example.gebruiker.tvnaardentoernooien.Cluka2.onPostExecute(Cluka2.java:57)
            at com.example.gebruiker.tvnaardentoernooien.Cluka2.onPostExecute(Cluka2.java:16)

Comment: have you initialized the context as said you before via Constructor?

Comment: Constructor of CluKa2 class? Unfortunately not.

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya you are passing list to ArrayAdpater's constructor, you should pass result.

Comment: @D.Bronder : please pass this and try out the same code.

Comment: @eric247 : No, I need to pass the list for creating arrayadapter.

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya pass what?

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya I got it, what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BhavesPatadiya I got a NullPointerException now. Will a try catch nullpointerexception work?

Comment: I know why you got that, it's because of this line: listView.findViewById(R.id.Toernooien); Your variable listView is null.

Comment: Please describe how are you executing your Asynctask. post lines here

Comment: Thank you very much for help, but I have hopefully one final question. To get the list in the list view you should use a list adapter. When I delete the line for initiate the list view I got a error for the adapter.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        Toernooien.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

Comment: Its really difficult to understand now. can you please upload your whole Activity class here in your question itself?

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya I adjusted the code to your specification and I added the activity code.

Comment: Please see my edit. I hope now your app run as expected.

Comment: and the setAdapter in the cluka2 class? There is the error   Toernooien.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);  the setAdapter has still the error of cannot resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your AsyncTask's result is `String`, but in your onPostExecute method you are expecting a List. This is the correct code

```
public class Cluka2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

Document document = null;
public List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView = null;
Context context = null;


public Cluka2(ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("https://tennisnaarden.planmysport.com/portal/page/pmsportal30/TVNaarden/Toernooien/Clubtoernooi").get();

        Elements elements = document.select("#pcnt1383_8158836_1383_4326089_4326089 td:first-child");

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

            list.add(elements.get(i).text());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}


protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    ListView Onderdelen = (ListView) listView.findViewById(R.id.Toernooien);
    Onderdelen.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

}
```

Comment: I tried this solution already. The problem is. Method does not override from superclass.

Comment: I am sorry, i just saw this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.  Which means we have to remove the @Override annotation.

Comment: on the website they say. The method doInBackGround should be override en mostly the method onPostExecute should be overridden.

Comment: If you are using Android studio then take your cursor inside this class and press Ctrl + O. You should be able to Override onPostExecute from there.

Comment: thanks @eric247 I have always configuring out how this worked.